# 404 Not Found Error when running reports

Tags: error, error-page

We moved our WordPress site from one cPanel account to another whilst changing domains. Everything in CiviCRM seemed to be working OK. But we've just hit a problem.

I can go to Reports -> Contact Reports -> Contact List - and get the screen with columns, filters, sorting OK.

But when I try to Refresh Results, or Print etc I get a 404 Not Found error.

Any help or hints of where to look would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the URLs that don't work? You can redact the site name if you'd like.  That will help people to help you.

Comment: An example URL:
http://mysite.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/report/instance/39

Answer (score 0):

Most common reason I have run into a 404 error when I've moved accounts? File permission issues. Usually there are some files that are attached to the wrong user/group, typically. Your host should be able to look at the logs for you and pinpoint the file(s), directory(ies), etc where the permission errors are happening. I like it if I can get into a chat with them, as I can then run the process, generate the error, and they can see it in the logs.